# Ignore time offsets in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame made up of times (and occasionally an NaN). I would like to remove the timezone offsets. Any ideas how to do this?

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'t':['2014-01-25 07:53:59-05:00', '2013-12-09 20:04:29+01:00', np.NaN]})
print d
a = pd.to_datetime(d.t)
a
```

Output:

```
                          t
0  2014-01-25 07:53:59-05:00
1  2013-12-09 20:04:29+01:00
2                        NaN

0   2014-01-25 12:53:59
1   2013-12-09 19:04:29
2                   NaT

Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In the conversion `to_datetime`, the times are converted to UTC. This is not desirable. Any idea how to keep that conversion from happening? I'd prefer to do this in Pandas.

Desired Output:

```
0   2014-01-25 07:53:59
1   2013-12-09 20:04:29
2                   NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop the NaN and then strip the offset and then do the conversion:

```
In [19]: 
# create the dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame({'t':['2014-01-25 07:53:59-05:00', '2013-12-09 20:04:29+01:00', np.NaN]})

d

Out[19]:

                           t
0  2014-01-25 07:53:59-05:00
1  2013-12-09 20:04:29+01:00
2                        NaN

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [20]:
# need to drop the NaN in order for the conversion to work
d.dropna(inplace=True)
# strip the offset
d.t = d.t.apply(lambda x : x[:-6])

d
Out[20]:

                     t
0  2014-01-25 07:53:59
1  2013-12-09 20:04:29

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [21]:
# now convert to datetime
d.t = pd.to_datetime(d.t)

d

Out[21]:

                    t
0 2014-01-25 07:53:59
1 2013-12-09 20:04:29

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [22]:

d.dtypes

Out[22]:

t    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

as @DSM pointed out you could do this in a single step (this also handles NaN's too):

```
d.t = pd.to_datetime(d.t.str[:-6])
```

would also work

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, but isn't there a way to do this without editing the string explicitly?

Comment: Not that I can think of as the offset is automatically parsed

Comment: You could simplify it a bit by using `.str`, e.g. `pd.to_datetime(d.t.str[:-6])`. (This would automatically handle `NaN`s too.)

Comment: @DSM yes that would be more compact